# How to get all mentions from a message

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I made a function which needs 2 mentions, so I first check the size with:

```js
if (message.mentions.members.size == 2)
```

It works, but then I need to get both mentions. The following works, but it only gets me the first one:

```js
message.mentions.members.first()
```

I've also tried other ways to get both mentions, like this one below, that returns `undefined`.

```js
message.mentions.members[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first()` takes an optional count parameter if you see [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=first).
You can use this to return an array of the members, like so:

```js
message.members.first(2);
```

The reason `mentions.members[0]` doesn't work is because `members` is a `Collection` (a discord.js enhancement of a map) which uses a snowflake as a key, 0 is not a valid snowflake and thus returns `undefined`.

Comment: Maps can't be accessed with `[key]` format anyway; `0` not being among the keys doesn't matter (it would be `.get(0)`)